# Why do we take the value of the constant in Coulomb's law as $\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, physical-constants, coulombs-law

Why do we take the value of the constant in Coulomb's law as $\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$?

Answer (score 0):

By Cavendish torsion balance, similar to the measure of gravitational constant.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment

Comment: Please do not post answer with only a link, but try to explain what it is about, such that people understand it without following the link. Links may die over time.